# -bash: export: not a valid identifier

Tags: bash, environment-variables, bashrc, hadoop

Whenever I open a terminal, I always end up with this same error.

```
-bash: export: `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin:/usr/local/hadoop/bin': not a valid identifier
```

And when I run command lines, I get errors like this:

```
-bash: sudo: No such file or directory
```

I can't even edit `~/.bashrc` through `gedit ~/.bashrc` which I think could be the problem. `echo $PATH` gives me an empty line.

All this stuff happens under my personal account. There's a dedicated hadoop user account, which I created specifically for running hadoop and that works fine without a glitch.

In the process of hadoop setup, which involves editing environment variables, I edited `~/.bashrc` as instructed by some tutorials.

What could be the problem, and how might I fix it?

Comment: looks like you have a different tick at the start than at the end.
can you `sudo gedit ~/.bashrc`?

Comment: Ye just change your  ` to a normal ' and it should work fine.

Comment: Did you try to edit your `~/.bashrc` and `~/.profile` by another user with enough privileges?

Comment: Btw. since your $PATH isn't working you have to tell the shell exactly where which command is. That means you would need to write something like /usr/bin/sudo /bin/vi /home/user/.bashrc or .profile and correct the issues

Comment: well, gedit ~/.bashrc  solved my problem :)  thank you so much

Answer (score 3):

Probably your .bashrc or .profile is messedup.

Your gedit will not start if it is not in path and since your path is empty it is not in the path.

You should first establish a good enough path.

```
export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

And then you should be able to start gedit. Alternativelly you could just run gedit with its whole path. Like:

```
/usr/bin/gedit
```

Comment: Thank you very much indeed. At least I can start to debug by running command lines.

Comment: @JamesWong the error message suggests it's running `export $PATH` instead of `export PATH`, so look for that in particular.